# IF in sql "Invalid column name"

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, mysql-error-1064

```
DECLARE @resultado int;
SET @resultado = (SELECT COUNT(serial) FROM inventario 
WHERE serial ='strSerialNumber'); 
IF @resultado = 1 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE inventario SET simnao ='strVariavel8', local ='strVariavel1', portaria ='strVariavel9', galpao ='strVariavel2', sala ='strVariavel3', ute ='strVariavel4', ramal ='5213', centrodecusto ='strVariavel6', etiquetaMonitor ='strVariavel7', data ='date', hora ='time'
    WHERE serial ='strSerialNumber'
END 
IF (@resultado = 1) and (data = '') 
BEGIN
    UPDATE inventario SET simnao ='strVariavel8', local ='strVariavel1', portaria ='strVariavel9', galpao ='strVariavel2', sala ='strVariavel3', ute ='strVariavel4', ramal ='5213', centrodecusto ='strVariavel6', etiquetaMonitor ='strVariavel7', data ='date', hora ='time'
END
IF @resultado = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO inventario (serial, hostname, simnao, usuario, local, portaria, galpao, sala, UTE, ramal, centrodecusto, etiquetamonitor, data, hora) 
    VALUES ('strSerialNumber','strHostname','strVariavel8','strUsuario','strVariavel1','strVariavel9','strVariavel2','strVariavel3','strVariavel4','3215','strVariavel6','strVariavel7','date','time')
END
```

I have this code, this should be working, but sql acuses that i dont have a column name called 'data', but i surely have, if i change 'data' for any other column, sql accuses the same error but with the other column name, someone could help ?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server...? Data is a reserverd word in SQL, i.e. needs to be delimited "data".

Comment: You can use column names only inside SQL statements not from Transact-SQL. `data` in the `IF` isn't inside an SQL statement.

Comment: "data" isn't defined anywhere.  You're using it like a variable, not a column name.  How is SQL Server supposed to know that's a column name, and how is it supposed to know which row to compare with ''?  If "data" is a column on the table "inventario", then you need to select the specific column from the specific row you're interested in, in order to get at the value of the column.

Comment: You are using SQL Server syntax and getting a MySQL error?  There are lots of issues with the code.  Please tag the question appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to change the IF statement to something like this:

```
IF (@resultado = 1) AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inventario 
                                WHERE serial = 'strSerialNumber' AND data = '')
```

This checks the value of 'data' for the single row you found where the serial number is 'strSerialNumber' for the empty string, and if that row exists, returns true.  If the value is not '', then that row doesn't exist, and the IF test will fail, which I think is what you want here.

Answer (score 0):

the answer was declare one variable to data, like this:

```html
DECLARE @resultado int; 
DECLARE @data1 varchar(15); 
SET @data1 = (SELECT data FROM inventario WHERE serial ='strSerialNumber'); 
SET @resultado = (SELECT COUNT(serial) FROM inventario WHERE serial ='strSerialNumber'); 
IF @resultado = 1 AND @data1 IS NOT NULL OR @data1 != '' 
BEGIN 
SET @resultado = 10 
END 
IF (@resultado = 1) AND @data1 is null or @data1 = ''
BEGIN 
UPDATE inventario SET simnao ='strVariavel8 ', local ='strVariavel1', portaria ='strVariavel9', galpao ='strVariavel2', sala ='strVariavel3', ute ='strVariavel4', ramal ='7567', centrodecusto ='strVariavel6', etiquetaMonitor ='strVariavel7', data ='date', hora ='time' WHERE serial ='strSerialNumber' 
set @resultado = 5
END
```